# Как у Яндекс карты по нажатию вызвать большой экран на кастомной кнопке?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Как у Яндекс карты по нажатию вызвать большой экран на кастомной кнопке?
Мой код выглядит так:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

        function init () {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [59.220501, 39.891523], 
                zoom: 12,
                controls: ['fullscreenControl']
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            })

            var btnFullscreen = new ymaps.control.Button({
                options: {
                    layout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        "<div class='customZoomBtn'>fullscreen<div/>"
                    ),
                    maxWidth: 150
                }
            });
            myMap.controls.add(btnFullscreen, {
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: '25px',
                    right: '25px'
                }
            });
            btnFullscreen.events.add('click', function (event) {
                myMap.enterFullscreen()
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([59.220501, 39.891523], {
                balloonContent: 'цвет <strong> какой то</strong>',
                iconCaption: 'текст 2'
            }, {
                preset: 'islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption'
            }));

        }
```

Проблема я так понимаю в вызове, потому что он пишет, что это не функция

```
btnFullscreen.events.add('click', function (event) {
            myMap.enterFullscreen()
        });
```

Напишите пожалуйста ПРИМЕРЫ кода что бы я с ними поэкспериментировал и потыкался, а не ссылку на статью

Answer (score 1):

У каждой карты уже есть свой собственный менеджер контейнера карты, доступный как **[map.container](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container.html)** .

Для перехода в полноэкранный режим вам следует вызвать [map.container.enterFullscreen();](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container.html#method_detail__enterFullscreen)
Для выхода - соответственно [map.container.exitFullscreen()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container.html#method_detail__exitFullscreen)